# Google Cloud Service Accounts with limited permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to use a service account to have one my scripts create regular disk snapshots. It seems to be that have to give this service account the role of "EDITOR", so it has write access.

What I am not seeing is any way to limit this accounts to snapshots. If an attacker can access the keys of this service account, they would be able to delete the disks, delete compute resources and so on.

I am sure I am missing something here. Where in the UI can I setup the permissions?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question so I provide you with the steps to create a custom role for your service account to permit it to create snapshots only.

On your `Google Cloud Console`, go to `IAM & Admin`, on the left menu click on `Roles`, now on the roles list find `Compute Storage Admin`:

[image]

Click on `Create role from this role`, name the new role, for example `Compute Snapshot Creator`. From the permission list remove those permissions that are not desirable for your use case (like `compute.x.delete`, `compute.x.resize`, `compute.images.x`, etc).

Save your custom role and assign it to the service account.

For more information about `Identity and Access Management (IAM) Roles` visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam).

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. The create role page on Google's website says the feature is in alpha though and you can't sign up without special approval.